# How can I call php's folder location directory in function include?

Tags: php

Here is the link of my folder directory.

[image]

Lets say that I am currently on **inquisition/lib.register.php** and i wanted to call **connections.php** in include_once() php function.and pages/page.accountupgrade.php.

How should I do it? 
**./ or ../ or just direct file name(ex. "page.accountupgrade.php"**

thanks!

Comment: why don't you just try it :) `./` and `../` are only two and is easy to test anyway

Comment: That's a great idea that I didn't thought about but the problem is my friend. The trail and error methods sometimes mess up the code, which I do not want to do. Espacially, when my folder is already freaking complex.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *`__DIR__`* magic constant :

```
include_once(__DIR__.'/../../pages/page.accountupgrade.php');
```

Chris

Comment: Umm, sir what the heck is /../../?

Comment: Please explain it? Thanks

Comment: .. is "one folder up" so ../.. is 2 folders up, of course you need to separate those with directory-separators which are / on *nix.

Comment: __DIR__ points to the folder of the running script so based on your structure you should go 2 folders up to access the pages folder